# File Chooser intent causes app to crash when selecting one file

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, onactivityresult

As the name of the question implies, i'm having a weird bug with the intent file chooser.
My intent allows me to select more than one file. When i select more than one file, the app doesn't crash. It's all good. I am able to play all the files selected. But, when i select one file, it crashes with an weird exception (Probably null data?).
See, i implemented a Songlist (it's a mutable list of type Uri). It's supposed to receive a Uri returned by the intent and add to it.
Thanks in advance.

The code for the Intent Calling and ActivityResult are Below.

IntentCalling

```
fun onMusicFileChooserClicked(v: View) {
        val intent = Intent()
                .setType("audio/*")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 111)
    }
```

ActivityResult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            for (i in 0 until data?.clipData!!.itemCount) {
                val uri = data?.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri
                songlist.add(uri)

            }

            selectfilesucess = true
            updateMetaData()
        }
    }
```

Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: kalves.multimediacenter, PID: 19399
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=111, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/86BD-1E10:DCIM/Camera/03. Do What I Gotta Do.mp3 flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }} to activity {kalves.multimediacenter/kalves.multimediacenter.MainActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4560)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4603)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6836)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                   Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                      at kalves.multimediacenter.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:179)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7274)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4556)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4603) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6836) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

The thing is i wasn't checking for null pointers. Basically, i had to check if clipdate == null, if true, it's a single file. If not, it's multiple files.
Silly me. Hope this helps someone.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
            val clipdata = data.clipData
            if(clipdata!=null){
                for (i in 0 until data?.clipData!!.itemCount) {
                    val uri = data?.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri
                    songlist.add(uri)

                }
            }else{
                val uri = data?.data
                songlist.add(uri)
            }

        }
```